# Rules - anonymous users redirected to user/login prevents request new password link from working

Tags: rules, users

I'm using the rules module with drupal 7 in order to redirect anonymous users to the login page.

Events: Drupal is initializing
Conditions: User has role(s) - Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: anonymous user
NOT Text comparison - Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:url], Matching text: user/login
Actions: Page redirect - Parameter: URL: user/login

My problem is I need the "request new password" to work. How do I tell Rules to ignore clicks to user/password?

This is the current setup for the Actions but it doesnt work.
[image]

When a user gets to the login page I want them to be able to click Request New Password and not be redirected back to user/login.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a condition to your redirection rule like this :

1. **Path has url alias**
2. **Value** : user/password
3. **Negate** : True

Edit :

It must be something like this :

[image: Rules negate condition]

Comment: Could you clarify Negate:true. Should Negate be checked or unchecked?

Comment: negate true = checked

Comment: I've edited mu answer. Check the screenshot